# How to configure testng?

Tags: maven, testng

I'm confused with configuring testng suites. I have 10 testng suites, that I want to group with one testng suite, but I'm not sure where the proper configuration should go. Can the 10 test suites have different configs? Should it be stored in the controlling suite? Or should it go in the maven pom file?

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" verbose="1" name="Collection"
   skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" junit="false" parallel="methods"
   data-provider-thread-count="1" annotations="JDK">

  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="test.xml"/>
    <suite-file path="test1.xml"/>
    <suite-file path="test2.xml"/>
    <suite-file path="test3.xml"/>
    <suite-file path="test4.xml"/>
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```